# How can I access root domain from subdomain?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, hosting, shared-hosting

I have the domain [thorin-apps.tk](http://thorin-apps.tk/) and the subdomain [app.thorin-apps.tk](http://app.thorin-apps.tk/) for a mobile/web-app version. Both domains hosted with Hostinger (a shared hosting service), I don't have access to the Apache configuration, I have limited SSH access and I don't have the possibility to create symlinks. The file structure for the domain is as shown below:

```
public_html
 |
 |--- app (directory for subdomain)
 |     |---- index.html
 |     |---- .htaccess
 |
 |--- js
 |--- img
 |--- css
 |--- ... some other folders ...
 |
 |--- .htaccess
 |--- index.html
```

I accomplished being able to access files with the following `.htaccess`-code, but then all the links tapped will redirect to main domain and I still can't do AJAX requests, because of `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No` so it's not close to being a solution for the problem:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(app\.)?thorin-apps\.tk$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(js/.+)$ http://thorin-apps.tk/$1 [L,NC,R]
    RewriteRule ^(css/.+)$ http://thorin-apps.tk/$1 [L,NC,R]
    RewriteRule ^(ATH/.+)$ http://thorin-apps.tk/$1 [L,NC,R]
    RewriteRule ^(bootstrap/.+)$ http://thorin-apps.tk/$1 [L,NC,R]
    RewriteRule ^(img/.+)$ http://thorin-apps.tk/$1 [L,NC,R]
```

I have also tried adding a `<base>`-tag to the head of the `app/index.html` like this: `<base href="https://thorin-apps.tk/" />` but all that got me was lots of console errors saying the resources were insecure. And it caused the whole subdomain to stop responding and I got timeout errors in the console.

I would be very grateful if anyone could get me out of the horrible headache I've had trying to fix this.

Comment: Please share what you have already tried.

Comment: I've done that now @MikeRockett

Comment: I'm afraid your question is unclear to me. You say you want all links for the subdomain to be relative to the public directory, but you're not stating what the links are currently relative to. As such, I can't identify your actual problem.

Comment: Currently, the links are relative to `public_html/app`, I want them to be relative to `public_html` @MikeRockett

Comment: If your subdomain's document root is `app` (that is, requesting `app.thorin-apps.tk` serves `app/index.html`, then you won't be able to access anything above `app` (like `public_html/js/*`) in the subdomain context.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my problem. But I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this. I've now made a `.htaccess`-code that allows me to access the files, but not do AJAX-requests. I'll  update my question.

Comment: You need to perform an **internal** redirect to a **file** not an **external** redirect to a **URL**. The browser has to get the resource from the same origin, it does not good for the browser to ask the same origin for a resource only for the server to tell it to go to a different origin to get it.

Comment: Okay @Quentin I do not have any experience with `.htaccess` whatsoever and I am fairly new to coding as well. So I do not know what you are talking about.

Comment: @tjespe — http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Your problem is regarding Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. Read more about that here: http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Comment: Thanks for the link @MikeRockett but I tried the code and it did not work. I do not think my host allows me to modify HTTP-headers

Comment: I don't know of any hosts who do that - they would loose customers very quickly, because nothing would work. Which `.htaccess` file dod you put the header in?

Comment: Both @MikeRockett + it's worth mentioning that Hostinger is a free web-hosting company.

Comment: I see, then perhaps they simply do not allow CORS.

Comment: @MikeRockett That is a possibility, they do not allow symlinks for example